# server doesn't find a file though it is there

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

when i was working on eclipse, everthing was good,

now i deployed my web app on apache on a server

i am getting this error in the log:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.29-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.29\webapps\IVRServer\WEB-INF\classes\images\one.png (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

but the file is there

look please:

[image]

this image from the server, the file is there

why i am getting wrong?
i access the file like this

image = new File(classLoader.getResource("images/two.png").getFile());

Comment: Can you please post code here? the snippet where you are accessing this file.

Comment: Could be related to trying to access the file with the path URL-encoded.

Comment: @DBug  the code I posted normally fixes this kind of problem

Comment: @BilalShah i added the code

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina please check my update, your code is different than mine, plus you are telling me to add a folder inside web-inf which is a folder that i didn't create from the first place, think about it

Comment: Then is CATALINA_HOME set to: C:\Program%20Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.29-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.29?  If so, change the "%20" to a space (" ").

Comment: @DBug that path is being generated automatically, you can see my code, i never put that path.

Comment: `getClass().getResource("images/two.png")` try this

Comment: yes, I know.  I believe tomcat generates the path based on CATALINA_HOME.  Specifically, getResource() assumes a path relative to the base of the classes, which in tomcat would be %CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\app\WEB-INF\classes, so that's why I was asking

Comment: Instead of classloader try getClass ().getResource ("/images  with leading /

Comment: @Jan that gives me null exception, the file not found

Comment: @DBug help pleaes i don't know what to do

Comment: @DBug you were right, when i changed the loaction of apache to c directly it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

usually WEB-INF is a protected directory in order to store many usefull files for your app.
Your web-content should be stored in a dedicated folder located above the WEB-INF folder (have a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107152/where-to-store-static-files-like-html-css-javascript-in-a-jetty-project)) because the WEB-INF folder cannot be accessed from a web request but only by your app.